# Testing correlation between two polygon features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, spatial-statistics, correlation

I am working on a project looking at county boundaries for the state of California. I have 2 polygon datasets with this same geographic boundary, and these datasets, when mapped individually, visually appear to have a spatial correlation. Polygons are mapped according to numerical attribute values, which range widely on both datasets.

Wondering what the best method might be to test for a correlation between these datasets?

Comment: You may want to review previous [Questions on Correlation using ArcGIS for Desktop](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/correlation+arcgis-desktop) here.

Comment: I am using shape files in ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: If both shapefiles are of identical spatial features, you can skip most of the steps in FelixIP's answer. If they both share a unique ID field (FIPS, county name, etc.), you can simply join one to the other. It doesn't sound like this is a necessarily spatial issue; is that correct?

Comment: Why not run a simple spatial linear regression to see behavior and direction of each polygon in the relation.

Answer (score 1):

1. Intersect 2 layers
2. Add field [Times] and calculate it using 2ndNumeric*ShapeArea
3. Summarise field [Times] and [ShapeArea] using first layer UniquPolygonId
4. Divide [Sum_Times] by [Sum_Area], this will give you weighted second layer numeric
5. Transfer result to 1st polygon table and check the correlation between 2 columns, i.e. 1st numeric and weighted one